# Ruby array map and join in one loop

Tags: ruby, arrays, theory

**Array exemple**

```
[
 [
   "Francis",
   "Chartrand",
   "email@email.com"
 ],
 [
   "Francis",
   "Chartrand",
   "second_email@email.com"
 ],...
]
```

**Result wanted**

```
"email@email.com, second_email@email.com, ..."
```

**My solution (two loop)**

```
array.map{|a| a[2]}.join(", ")
```

Is it possible to do this with one loop?

Comment: I wouldn't consider `join` to be a loop.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ahah not for a homework, just for refactoring and personal informations

Comment: Seems more like refuctoring to me. `map`/`join` is common idiom, don't stray from it.

Comment: Well. you could consider join to be a loop, when you look at the runtime ([it is implemented using a O(n) loop](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/array.rb#L845))

Comment: I believe that map/join is better, and faster than one loop cyle with a condition check.

Comment: map & join are faster https://gist.github.com/chartrandf/6779594

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [Enumerable#inject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) we can do the task in one loop:

```
a = [
  ["Francis", "Chartrand", "email@email.com"],
  ["Francis", "Chartrand", "second_email@email.com"]
]
a.inject(nil) {|str, arr| str ? (str << ', ' << arr[2]) : arr[2].dup}
#=> "email@email.com, second_email@email.com"
```

However, this is an academic thing only, because `map`/`join` is faster and more readable anyways. See [this benchmark](https://gist.github.com/tessi/6779700/):

```
             user   system    total       real
map/join 1.440000 0.000000 1.440000 ( 1.441858)
inject   2.220000 0.000000 2.220000 ( 2.234554)
```

Comment: Nice answer, but map and join still faster http://gist.github.com/chartrandf/6779594

Comment: @FrancisChartrand Of course map and join is not only faster, but is more straightforward. And that is what everyone is telling you. But since you insist on not using map and join, and since you insist on doing it in one loop, and since you do not mention the speed in the question, this is what you get.

Comment: FrancisChartrand, sawa you both are right. map/join is faster (I have created [a second benchmark](https://gist.github.com/tessi/6779700) where my answer is optimized for performance (so its a little more fair)). I better state that in my answer :)

Comment: @tessi Pay attention that the optimization you have done alters the original array. After executing it `a[0]` is `["Francis", "Chartrand", "email@email.com, second_email@email.com"]`.

Comment: @toro2k good catch. Fixed it (which makes the code look a little clumsy). But we all agree to use `map`/`join` anyways, so clumsiness shouldn't really matter :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach, but it may not be especially fast.

```
s = ''          
array.flatten.each_slice(3) {|e| s += e.last + ', '} 
s.chop.chop
```

Here's another:

```
array.transpose[2].join(', ')
```

I assume you wanted a single string of email addresses for the entire array.